# Product of all divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, divisor-counting-function

> Prove that $\prod_{d \mid n}d=n^{v(n)/2}$ where $v(n)$ is the sum of divisors function.

We have if $n=p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}} \dots p_{k}^{a_{k}}$ then $v(n)=(a_{1} +1)(a_{2}+1) \dots (a_{k} +1)$
substituting this in the expression  does not reach anything, is there any way to express $\prod_{d \mid n}d$  easier to relate to the expression of $v(n)$, or I can proceed to make this demonstration. Thanks

Comment: Every divisor $d$ occurs in a pair with $n/d$, so you have to count the number of such pairs.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases to consider, $n$ not a perfect square and $n$ a perfect square.

If $n$ is not a perfect square, the divisors of $n$ can be split into groups of $2$, with product $n$. If $d(n)$ is the **number of divisors** function, then there are $d(n)/2$ groups of two, and therefore our product is $n^{d(n)/2}$.

A similar argument deals with $n$ a perfect square. We leave it to you to do the details. In this case, the number of divisors function wll be odd, say $d(n)=2k+1$. If $n=m^2$, then one of the terms in our product is $m$, that is, $n^{1/2}$. Use the pairing argument of the preceding paragraph to deal with he other divisors of $n$.

Comment: No need to separate into two cases, just use $(\prod_{d\mid n} d)^2 = (\prod_{d\mid n} d)(\prod_{d\mid n} n/d)$.

Comment: Nice, perhaps slightly less concrete.

Comment: @ André Nicolas: Not less concrete , $d|n \Longleftrightarrow n/d|n$